# Docusign for Salesforce integration assistance

Tags: email, salesforce, docusignapi

In the last days, I have started to integrate DocuSign for SalesForce, and I have some questions and issues :

1. Can one define ahead and anchor the location for signature and other fields that the customer has to fill? So that our sales reps won't have to go through each document and plant the fields in the envelope, and instead it would be immediately ready to send?
2. Is it possible to define default Email sender as a Queue email/Department Email, and not the user email? Also, can the final email with the signed document be sent to the queue email?
3. Can I define the subject and the body of the email on Hebrew (it's a right to left language!)
4. Can I use in the email subject and body dynamic parameters from SF objects? Like from the opportunity or the account.
5. I did some tests, but the signed document doesn't show in the Document status section in the opportunity. What might be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can, you can set up a template with predefined tabs or anchor text depending on how you are using DocuSign here is the how-to: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-working-with-templates
2. That email address would need an account, personally I would not set it up that way, if the end goal is to get a copy of the final doc to that mail queue I would add that email address as a recipient (gets a copy)
3. you can set up custom languages for each recipient: start a new envelope, add recipients, in the Message to All Recipients, select Custom email and language for each recipient.here is the how to:https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-recipient-language
4. Yes, custom buttons in Salesforce allow you to dynamically define the Subject and Email Message of an envelope using any field in the Salesforce object.
5. It sounds like your Connect for Salesforce may not be authenticated, look and see if it is for just one envelope or for all, perhaps disconnect and reconnect. DocuSign had a support article on this: https://support.docusign.com/articles/Why-aren-t-my-completed-envelopes-being-shown-in-Salesforce